# Yii2 Insert Multiple data of same model using one form

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2 and trying to insert multiple data of one model using in the same form it's like invoices system inserting multiple products by same form.

my view orm is :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[0]studentName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('NAME') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[0]studentEmail')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('EMAIL') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[0]studentCode')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('CODE') ?>

    <!--  -->

    <?= $form->field($model, '[1]studentName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('NAME') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[1]studentEmail')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('EMAIL') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[1]studentCode')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('CODE') ?>

    <!--  -->

    <?= $form->field($model, '[2]studentName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('NAME') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[2]studentEmail')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('EMAIL') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, '[2]studentCode')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('CODE') ?>

    ....    

    <?= $form->field($model, 'note')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('NOTE') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and My controller create action is :

```
public function actionCreateClass($ssid)
    {
        $program = new Program();  $model = new ClassC();  $session = $this->findSession($ssid)

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $program->title = 'PHP'. date('Y') .$session->title;
            $program->note = $model->note;
            $program->save();

            foreach ($model->studentCode as $SC)
            {
                $student = $this->findStudent($SC);

                $model;
                $model->program = $program->program_id;
                $model->save();
            }

            return $this->redirect(['programe', 'id' => $program->program_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('createClass', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

I tried using var_dump to know what I get as return but my var_dump return NULL in `var_dump($model)`. I also tried to use

`(Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()))` but I get error

`Call to a member function formName() on array`

Comment: This $form->field($model, '[0]studentName')-> means every $model[0] is declared as $model[0] = new ClassC(); in your controller

Comment: yes that what I want; from one form I insert multiple time model : model>studentname , model->studentemail , model->studentcode. Multiple time ; for 1st student  and 2nd student and 3rd student......................

Comment: OK every array inside $model must be an istance of model ClassC ex $model[0] = new ClassC() for 1st student $model[1] = new ClassC(); for 2nd student and so on

Comment: Yes that exactly what I'm trying to do but i didn't success , its gonna be $model[0] = new ClassC, and insert data , $model[1] = new ClassC and insert data for 2nd student .........but my code is not working

Comment: Sorry but i don't find in your code the declaration of the models. You have to create it before this  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))

Comment: I declare it, but I post on my question actionCreateClass($ssid) function, but I already declare it "use frontend\models\ClassC;" and I call it before $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()).

Comment: Do you mean this? $model = new ClassC();

Comment: yes that right I already declared

Comment: In your case you can't declare this way. you need an array of models , and to do this you need to declare this way $model[1] = new ClassC; $model[2] = new ClassC; n models declaration for every [n] Students

Comment: is not working, also $model is not always the same number some time there is 3 student some time is only 2 student or one some time are 4 so I can't create for every student a model, like $model[0], $model[1], I want to create a foreach loop. but I didn't success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186342/discussion-between-sfili-81-and-bynd).

Comment: are you sure it enters the `foreach ($model->studentCode as $SC)` ?

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam : Yes it's enter foreach the var_dump is inside foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in your foreach:

```
$model->id = NULL; //primary key(auto increment id) id
$model->isNewRecord = true;
$model->program = $program->program_id;
$model->save();
```

And remove $model; inside loop

Comment: not working still getting null; The id is auto increment

Answer (score 0):

this example might help you:

```
$modelsAddress = [new Address];
$modelsAddress = Model::createMultiple(Address::classname());
Model::loadMultiple($modelsAddress, Yii::$app->request->post());
foreach ($modelsAddress as $modelAddress) {
   $modelAddress->customer_id = $modelCustomer->id;
   $modelAddress->save();
}
```

1. you create multiple instances of desired model class using createMultiple.
2. then you load the data from the form using loadMultiple.
3. then you loop through all the instances and save them.

Comment: I get error : Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array on

 <?= $form->field($model, '[0]studentName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('NAME') ?>; I declared $model = [new ClassC] ....

Comment: you need to use an instance for the form, from the model , try  "return $this->render('createClass', [
            'model' => new ClassC(),
        ]);"

Comment: also you can check out this widget it might be helpful, https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform

Comment: I tried to find a solution from the widget but didn't help,